# Touch up inside button not working properly

Tags: xcode, swift, button, interface-builder

I am working on the UI for a game. On the title screen I have a variety of buttons on the screen. One button is a toggle button for allowing sound to be muted. I have the *selected* image being a mute image. And the *default* image being a full sound image. I have a connection to a view controller with the sound button. The connection is an action type that occurs when the button is touched up inside. The code for the button is:

```
@IBAction func soundButton(sender: UIButton) {
     sender.selected = sender.selected! 
}
```

When the app is first loaded, the title screen is shown. On the screen, the sound button displays that the sound is on. I can click and hold the button and the image doesn't change. Then when I release, the image changes. That works just how I want it to, it displays a mute image, but then when I click and hold the button again, to enable sound. The image changes as soon as I touch the button, **NOT** when I release after I touched it like it did the first time. This is not a huge bug, but I would still like to know why this might happen. And thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its odd that there's no function name. But.. I tested this in the absence of any other code, and it works as you would expect - the image doesn't change until touch UP is registered.

That said - there IS a visual change when the button is pressed. It doesn't have to do with the `selected` property though. It's part of the set of images you can define. `UIControlState.Highlighted`

Here's how I tested:
viewDidLoad:

```
thebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_dark"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
thebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_light"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

And my action for the button (on touch up inside):

```
@IBAction func tap(sender: AnyObject) {
    thebutton.selected = !thebutton.selected
}
```

Comment: I figured it out I believe what happened was that I had it so that there was highlighted can after the image. Therefore I need an image for highlighted because then it goes to default which is my other full sound image. So it was doing what I told it the whole time.

Comment: You could make a highlighted state for both images - perhaps darker or smaller. So that would give you a "pressed" state for both on and off. Sounds like you totally got it!